# How do I check if a Linux desktop system would blank screen after some timeout without waiting for that time?

Tags: linux, time, screensaver, timeout

Suppose there is some Linux-based desktop system with some less popular desktop environment.

I tried to make it not to turn off screen by using `xset s off` and `xset -dpms`, yet after 10 minutes screen still went blank.

How can I prepare system for constantly showing something important (e.g. for two hours) without actually doing long-term test and sitting and waiting for those two hours just to check?

Is there some appropriate method to "fast forward" the time to check how system would react to idly waiting? Or how can I find out the source (specific program or setting) if screen still got black?

Comment: Set it for 15 minutes, wait, check, and the if that works, 2 hours will work.

Comment: What I typically do is set the time for 1 minute, if it works for 1 minute, I know it works for any amount of time.

Comment: Now I suspect that screen may be blanked by laptop firmware. All those typical settings play would probably not affect it.